# Selecting an enemy from a non sorted weighted list

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, math

I have been itching my head as to why this is not working like it should. I have a list that changes probability of monster spawning every second. i want to select a random weighted enemy from this list. Somewhere im going wrong and i think it is around the `"EnemyToSpawnNext = Enemies[sorted[T].Key].Enemie[0].EnemyPrefab;"` area.

```
public GameObject EnemySelection()
{

    var sorted = TierProbability.Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, float>(i, x)).OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
    List<int> idx = sorted.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
    List<float> B = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();


    float P = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1);
    float Sum_prob = 0;
    for (int T = 0; T < TotalNumberofTiers; T++)
    {

        Sum_prob += sorted[T].Value; 
        print(Sum_prob);
        if (Sum_prob >= P)
        {
            EnemyToSpawnNext = Enemies[sorted[T].Key].Enemie[0].EnemyPrefab;

            break;
        }
    }
    return EnemyToSpawnNext;

}
```

the following is the difficulty adjustment function that created the list of probabilitys.

```
 public void DifficultyAdjustments()
{
    SecondsElapsed += 10; // for debugging

    Min_Tier += 10 * (End_Min_Tier - Start_Min_Tier) / (TimeinMinutes * 60);
    Peak_Tier += 10 * (End_Peak_Tier - Start_Peak_Tier) / (TimeinMinutes * 60);
    Max_tier += 10 * (End_Max_Tier - Start_Max_Tier) / (TimeinMinutes * 60);


    for (int T = 0; T < TotalNumberofTiers; T++)
    {
        if (T < Min_Tier)
        WeightT = 0;
    if (T > Max_tier)
        WeightT = 0;
    if (Min_Tier <= T & T < Peak_Tier)
        WeightT = 1 + (Max_weight - 1) / (Peak_Tier - Min_Tier) * (T - Min_Tier);
    if (Peak_Tier <= T & T < Max_tier)
        WeightT = 1 + (Max_weight - 1) / (Peak_Tier - Max_tier) * (T - Max_tier);
        TierWeights[T] = WeightT;
        TierProbability[T]  = WeightT / TierWeights.Sum();
    }
    print(EnemySelection()); // for debugging

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your P

```
 float P = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1);
```

this P always become zero

**Use this instead:**

float P = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);

Comment: you can simply use this  float P = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);

Comment: Dont forget to f or you can use max range as 2 depend on what you want. @Prime

Comment: For a random value between 0 and 1, you can use: [Random.value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html)